# Nominations Thread

Tags: discussion, election, election-2016, moderators

There are a few people I really feel ought to run for moderator and, apparently, I'm not allowed to nominate them directly as they must nominate themselves.  So, I asked [@GraceNote](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/users/7/grace-note) if there was a simple way to alert people that they ought to run and would have my support.

I was told that there are probably plenty of users in my boat and that other sites have had similar questions come up.  I was told that those stacks simply created a "Nominations Thread", and that it may be a good idea for us to do the same thing.

So here I am, creating that thread.  Please feel free to nominate people you would like to run, and perhaps a brief explanation of why you would support them.  If you see someone else has already nominated them, then just do what comes naturally: upvote them :).

**[tl;dr]**

***If you would like to suggest that someone run for moderator, please list their name here.***

---

If you've been suggested as a nominee, and would like to go ahead and nominate yourself for moderator, [please feel free to click this clause to be taken to the nomination page](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/election).  (The form link is at the bottom of the page.)

Answer (score 8):

I'd like to suggest that [voretaq7](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/users/64/voretaq7) nominate himself for moderator.  He is one of our current mods, and I feel he's done a stellar job of staying on top of his duties.  So nominate yourself already sir!